# eWam - how to add a picker using the application descriptor

Tags: windows, ewam

How does one add a picker to the eWam menu, using an application descriptor?

When I attempt to add a picker, I am unable to find the exact method by which to add the picker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The add a "Picker Bag Manager" entry point to an application descriptor:

1. navigate in eWAM to the application descriptors list on the run tab.
2. modify that app desc.
3. go to the desktop contents tab
4. Click the Group descriptor (aWFDesktopGroupDescriptor) under which you would like the add the picker.
5. Click the "Add others EP..." button.
6. Choose Picker bag manager.
7. Choose the class you want to pick. Ideally that class has a designated picker already, in which case you don't need to declare it on the PBM. if it is not set on the base class, you should set it on the base class, if this is not possible or you need to use a custom picker, declare it in the PBM entry point.
8. Remember to set the bitmaps
9. Remember to add Actions if necessary.
10. Save and test.